# Looking for a word that describes a dull or tedious question

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

This might be a slightly odd ask, but I'm looking for an adjective that might describe a question asked out of boredom. Something that is tedious and uninspired. I had something the other day but forgot to write it down and it's driving me up the wall. I believe it started with a 'p' and can't find anything in the thesaurus. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***an idle question***

> without any particular purpose:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idle)

An idle question is asked out of boredom, or sheer obstinacy.

Comment: Still struggling to find the 'P" word...

Comment: I found it at last. Perfunctory. Now that I think about it though, it might not be the best word to apply here. An idle question though... Thanks very much!

Comment: If you like the answer you should accept it.

Comment: @Anton For me, I expect that an accepted answer should only occur after a "trial" period of 24 hours...otherwise it might discourage other more relevant ideas from newer users. I believe that it is a long-accepted site etiquette.

Comment: @Cascabel Point taken. It was late. You are correct.